# How to authenticate using cloudcontrol REST API

Tags: api, rest, cloudcontrol

I am trying to use the Cloudcontrol REST API.

Has anybody used that API? I did not find out how to authenticate.

As an example, I tried https://api.devcctrl.com/app/APPMNAME/deployment/default/error/

I found : https://api.devcctrl.com/doc/#Token but I don't understand how exactly to use it.

An example would be great.

What I really want to do: I want to deploy an app using REST API. I cannot use the CLI tools due to missing python installation.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2):

First, in order to get the token, you need to send a HTTP `POST` request to `api.cloudcontrol.com/token/`using Basic Authentication using the email and password of your cloudControl account. You will get a JSON response like this:

`{"token": "<TOKEN_KEY>"}'`

You need this token key to authenticate for all other requests to the API. To do so, add an `Authorization` Header to your request with this content:

`Authorization` -> `"cc_auth_token="<TOKEN_KEY>""`

Furthermore, you might also need to set up some other headers for `PUT` or `POST` requests, like:

`Content-Type` -> `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

`Content-Length` ->  `<length of your parametrized url values, e.g. bar=baz&foo=qux>`

`Accept-Encoding` -> `"compress, gzip"`

You can find examples of this usage in the [pycclib](https://github.com/cloudControl/pycclib) (Python) or [gocclib](https://github.com/fern4lvarez/gocclib) (Go) libraries.